# How can I improve this JS reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different APIs that I've fetched from using `await Promise.all()`. They are assigned to a variable called `items`. API #1's `response` is an object that would look like this:

```
{
    total: 3,
    items: [
        {…},
        {…},
        {…}
    ]
}
```

API #2's `response` is just an array of objects.

Now I want to end up with an object looking like the `response` from API #1, using a reducer to add the length of API #2's to the `total` and ’merge’ the `response` from API #2 into the `items` array.

This is what I've gone for:

```
const items = results.reduce((accumulator, { response }) => {
    const total = response?.total ?? response?.length

    if(!accumulator?.items) {
        accumulator.items = []
    }

    accumulator.items = [
        ...accumulator.items,
        ...(response?.items ?? response)
    ]

    return ({
        ...accumulator,
        total: (accumulator?.total ?? 0) + total
    })
}, {})
```

My gut feeling is that there could definitely be a cleaner/more structured way of accomplishing the same result. Any major hiccups that I should re/-consider?

Comment: What is the shape of the objects from API 2?

Comment: _to end up with an object looking like the response from API #1, using a reducer to add the length of API #2's to the total and ’merge’ the response from API #2 into the items array_ - I'm wondering if we even need `.reduce` to achieve this. API #1 response is an object with 2 props `total`, `items`. And API #2 response is simply an array (which needs to be concatenated to API #1's `items`). Is this correct?

Comment: Same as in API #1, very basic:

    {
        "id": "d7ah183-as8ds8n",
        "title": "Example title"
    }

Comment: If my observation/assumption above is correct, then: `const targetObject = { total: api1.response.total + api2.response.length, items: [...api1.response.items, ...api2.response]};` <-- this should be the desired target.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please [edit] to clarify the problem.

Comment: @jsN00b yeah, the thing is that I want to build it more dynamic than that, i.e. what if I add more fetches to it, or if one of the API's are excluded for some reason.

Comment: _if one of the API's are excluded_ <-- I saw you are using optional-chaining and nullish coalescing operators (`?.` and `??`) and this should handle if either API 1 or 2 response is missing. And for this: _what if I add more fetches to it_ <--- my apologies, I don't quite comprehend what this means.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear and posting to the wrong forums. I meant if I add more endpoints that I fetch from, where I don't know if the `results` looks like the one from API #1 or #2.

Answer (score 2):

It seems overkill to even look at any `total`. You have the individual arrays, and by consequence lengths.

I would propose to use `flatMap` to concatenate all arrays, and only create a `total` property at the very end:

```js
const results = [
    { response: { total: 3, items: [1, 2, 3] } },
    { response: [4, 5, 6, 7] }
];

const items = (items => ({ items, total: items.length }))
        (results.flatMap(({response}) => response.items ?? response));

console.log(items);
```

Personally, I would not create the `total` property at all. `items.length` does all you need.

Comment: Was just about to post this. Could add a dedupe/merge if there may be overlap on the response arrays, but otherwise...

Comment: Alright, this was a pretty neat way of solving it! What if not all `items` are returned from API #1 in the first fetch, then I couldn't base the `total` on the `items.length`. Thoughts?

Comment: So what then would your `results` array look like? With your mention of `Promise.all`, we can assume that all fetching has completed. If you still want to end up with a `items` array where `total` is not equal to the `items.length`, then I am a bit lost at what you want to do with that...

Comment: So the endpoint that contains both `total` and `items` *can* have a limit of e.g. 5 (for pagination purposes). The other one is basically just a JSON file with an array, so I will always have the ’correct’ total of them both if I add `total` from #1 and the length of #2 together – but more `items` can be fetched/merge in a later instance.

Comment: You have to explain "in a later instance". Is `Promise.all` not returning *all* data? If not, then how will you decide which batch needs to have another follow-up request, since you have already merged all results into a single array? I think this goes beyond what you have asked in your question.

Comment: Not necessarily (for #1), no. This is all lives inside a function where I have a state called `hasFetched` and the cumulated `items`. `hasFetched` is set to true after the initial request and if the cumulated `items` are lower than `total`, then I fetch from #1 again with an offset (and again, until all `items` are fetched).

Comment: I understand the principle of fetching more until the total is reached, but my point is that this asynchronous process should lead to a completion when `Promise.all` resolves. If this is not the case, and this resolves while you still have more fetching to do, then redesign that part. If you start building the final combined array, you'll be too late to still fetch more. You'll want to build that final array only when you already have everything. I hope I get my point across?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243346/discussion-between-erik-blomqvist-and-trincot).